# call javascript function from imagebutton click asp.net 1.1

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datagrid

i have a javascript function:

```
      function confirmerSupprimer()
      {
        var confirm=confimrm("est vous sur de vouloir supprimer ce facturation");
        if(confimrm==false)
          return false;
      }
    </script>
```

inside a datagrid:
i have

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="15%"></HeaderStyle>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton id="ibEdit" runat="server" CommandName="update" ImageUrl="./Images/edit.gif" AlternateText="Editer"></asp:ImageButton>
                                    <asp:ImageButton id="ibDelete" runat="server" CommandName="delete" ImageUrl="./Images/del.gif"
                                                            AlternateText="Supprimer" OnClick="confirmerSupprimer();"></asp:ImageButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton id="ImageButton6" runat="server" CommandName="update" ImageUrl="images/save.gif"
                                        AlternateText="Valider"></asp:ImageButton>

                                    <asp:ImageButton id="ImageButton4" runat="server" CommandName="cancel" ImageUrl="./Images/cancel.gif"
                                        AlternateText="Annuler"></asp:ImageButton>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
```

Error:

BC30456: 'confirmerSupprimer' not a
a  member of 'ASP.Facturation_aspx'.

What's the pb

Answer (score 0):

This function is declared in **JavaScript** - your GridView is expecting a method declared in **C#**—that's why you're getting that error.

If you want to wire this image button up with that JavaScript function, you could add this call to the Attributes collection in your code behind.

```
<asp:DataGrid OnItemDataBound="yourDataGrid_RowDataBound" 

protected void yourDataGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item) return;

    ImageButton ib = e.Item.Cells[YourIndex].FindControl("ibDelete") as ImageButton;
    ib.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:return confirmerSupprimer()";
}
```

Comment: how can i add confirmation popup for the user?

Comment: @user594166 - just make sure you add RowDataBound to your Grid to point to this method

Comment: @user594166 - sorry, I see you're using asp.net 1.1 - I updated my code accordingly